# How to set css of different parts of a Material UI Dialog?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So this is a sample piece of code for Material Dialog

```
  <Dialog
    open={this.props.open}
    onClose={this.props.closeAtParent}
    PaperProps={{
      style: {
        minHeight: '75vh',
        minWidth: '75vw',
      },
    }}
    aria-labelledby="open-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="open-dialog-description"
  >
    <DialogTitle id="open-dialog-title">
      {this.props.dialogs[this.state.selected].title}
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="open-dialog-description">
        {this.props.dialogs[this.state.selected].desc}
      </DialogContentText>
      {this.imageIfExists()}
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      {this.populateButtons()}
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
```

Now as you can see I was able to set the dialog width and height through PaperPros but I am unable to set other properties like backdrop color and DialogActions' button alignment.

There is no documentation or SO available for the same which is so sad. They mention `classes` and `PaperProps` but do not talk about them.

My questions therefore are,

- How do I centre the buttons which by default are aligned at the right?
- Also, how do I change the backdrop color which is initially grey?

Comment: is this material-ui v1 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that

Comment: I think you should read that https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material-ui `Dialog` also inherits `Modal`Component you can use the `Props` of Modal to change the Backdrop color

[Modal API Description](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/)

`Button` in DialogActions are by default justified to `flex-end`. You can override this behaviour using classes property

```js
const styles = {
  backdrop: {
    backgroundColor: blue[100],
    color: blue[600],
  },
  action:{
    justifyContent:'inherit',
  }
};
```

```js
<Dialog
          BackdropProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.backdrop,
            }
          }}
          {...other}/>
```

```js
<DialogActions
           className={classes.action}>
```

Comment: One last thing, how do I set elevation? I know there's a key for that as well but cannot work it out.

Comment: Use PaperProps props for Dialog. Like this `<Dialog PaperProps={{
            elevation:24
          }}/>`

Answer (score 2):

you can use Grid to align your content, in this case your buttons as described in here: https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/

you can use **BackdropProps** to change backdrop values. use: https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/

(it clearly says: The properties of the Modal component are also available. You can take advantage of this behavior to target nested components)

so the final outcome will be:

```
<Dialog
 onClose={this.handleClose}
 {...other}
 BackdropProps={{
  classes: {
   root: classes.root
  }
 }}
 PaperProps={{
  style: {
    minHeight: "75vh",
    minWidth: "75vw"
  }
 }}
 aria-labelledby="open-dialog-title"
 aria-describedby="open-dialog-description"
 >
  <DialogTitle id="open-dialog-title">title</DialogTitle>
   <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText id="open-dialog-description">
     content
    </DialogContentText>
   </DialogContent>
   <DialogActions>
    <Grid container justify="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="raised" color="primary">
         test
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
   </DialogActions>
 </Dialog>
```

here is a working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/10vxmwqy7

hope this will help you.